# Why should the host window not have CS_HREDRAW and CS_VREDRAW window styles?

Tags: winapi, windows-ribbon-framework

I was reading the SimpleRibbon sample application and I noticed a curious line in the source:

```
wcex.style          = 0;    // Don't use CS_HREDRAW or CS_VREDRAW with a Ribbon
```

I can't find any reference on MSDN or elsewhere that explains why these window classes shouldn't be used in a window that contains a ribbon. Does anyone know what this is all about?

Cheers.

Sample code: [GitHub Windows-classic-samples - SimpleRibbon.cpp](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/WindowsRibbon/SimpleRibbon/CPP/SimpleRibbon.cpp)

Comment: When the `CS_HREDRAW` bit is set, then a horizontal size change causes the entire window to be redrawn. When not set, a horizontal size change causes only the newly exposed area to be drawn. Setting the `CS_VREDRAW` bit does the same but with vertical size changes. I'm not familiar with the Windows Ribbon Framework, but I'm guessing that you shouldn't redraw the ribbon every time the window changes size. Have you tried setting those bits and seeing what happens?

Comment: It is not obvious and a bit draconian in a sample.  They are perhaps trying to make it look good.  Expectation is that the ribbon subclasses your main window so it can detect basic messages like WM_SIZE.  Necessary to ensure the ribbon always fits across the window.  So the ribbon control itself won't need these class styles.  Your own app however likely does if it doesn't buy into DirectX wrappers like D2D.  So ignore it, use the styles and see what hits the fan.

Comment: The GitHub repository's [Issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/issues) tab is probably a better place to ask for clarification.

Comment: Presumably you get lots of ugly flickering.

Comment: So, my understanding after reading those comments is that the ribbon knows when to draw itself, but it still obeys requests to be redrawn, so the idea is avoid sending unnecessary redraw requests to the ribbon. CS_HREDRAW and CS_VREDRAW aren't harmful per se, but they will reduce efficiency and perhaps cause flickering if the ribbon repaints itself. So a 'real' application might have a separate window with whatever repaint styles are needed in the client area, or an app might be d2d or use WPF or whatever. Thanks guys, this has really helped!

Comment: Hi all, I had this question as I myself look at the sample. Upon reading your comments, it reminds me about returning FALSE on the WM_ERASEBKGND when using OpenGL in a CWnd. Perhaps the same trick needs to be performed for the ribbon?

Comment: @mynameisnafe Makes sense - especially if the ribbon is being drawn with something fancy like direct2d.

Answer (score 1):

check this link http://www.catch22.net/tuts/win32/flicker-free-drawing .

I was having terrible flickering when resizing my custom text view widget. Then this tutorial told me to remove CS_HREDRAW and CSVREDRAW. I immediately saw that flickering was gone! Now my question is, what the heck is the purpose of these styles. Since they only do bad.

Note that Windows 7 fixed flickering. So even if your app flickers crazy on Windows Xp, it will won't flicker on Windows 7.

Comment: Windows 7 (and Vista) use DWM and offscreen surfaces when rendering. I think this reduces the appearance of flicker because the app does not directly draw pixels to the screen - drawing with GDI is actually a lot slower in vista/7. You still get flicker, but it is a lot slower and less noticible.

Comment: But yes, I think CS_HREDRAW and CS_VREDRAW will cause severe flicker when resizing a window on windows XP and older if your window has a non-null brush for the background. On the other hand, it is obviously desirable to redraw a window if the size has changed! The article you have linked is a great discussion which I am reading now, thank you for sharing.

Comment: @fabspro I am happy to share as I was happy to learn. The least I can do is share. Not only is that article interesting but his entire website is a goldmine for win32 developers. It doesn't have everything about win32 development, but it has alot. On your other points. You don't need CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW to redraw a resized window. Those styles cause your entire window to be invalidated, rather than just the section which was  actually invalidated. And those styles cause severe flickering even if your hbrBackground brush is null.